# Parse.com Create with nested or related objects

Tags: parse-platform

Can someone please provide an example of how to save a parse.com object via the RESTApi for an object that contains a collection of other related objects?

so object A contains a list of object B where B is a pre-existing object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a related object like this:

```
{
  "__type": "Pointer",
  "className": "GameScore",
  "objectId": "Ed1nuqPvc"
}
```

Source: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-types

However, it's not recommended to store a large amount of data in a single instance.

> ...should not exceed 128 kilobytes in size.

Source: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-types/iOS

You might be better to create a linked table, e.g. if a 'User' (A) has many a 'Accounts/cars/objects' (B) then create a table `userObject` and use that to link the two other tables.