# How to filter objects with subquery?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

Usking **[shiki/kaiseki](https://github.com/shiki/kaiseki)** to interact with the Parse REST api. I'm trying to get all `A`s that do not have a related `B` for a user.

I know I can get Bs for a user:

```
parseClient.getObjects('B', {
  where: {
    user: { 
      __type: "Pointer",
      objectId: "id here",
      className: "_User"
    }
  },
  keys: 'a'
}, callback)
```

And then pluck object ids to get the bad A ids.

```
aIds = [ Bs ].map(function (b) {
  return b.a.objectId
})
```

And then query for As negative matching the id.

```
parseClient.getObjects('A', {
  where: {
    objectId: { $nin: aIds }
  }
}, callback)
```

But a user can have more B's than the query limit of 200. How can I rewrite it to use a subquery?

---

**$dontSelect**

Nested key param doesn't work, which makes something like this fall flat.

```
parseClient.getObjects('A', {
  where: {
    objectId: {
      $dontSelect: {
        query: {
          className: 'B',
          where: { user query },
        },
        key: 'a.objectId 
      }
    }
  }
}, callback)

// { code: 105, error: 'invalid field name: ' }
```

**$notInQuery**

There doesn't seem to be a way to put $notInQuery in the root of the `where` or to reference the current object.

```
parseClient.getObjects('A', {
  where: {
    $notInQuery: {
      className: 'B',
      where: { user query },
      key: 'a'
    }
  }
}, callback)

// { code: 102, error: 'Invalid key $notInQuery for find' }
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a limitation of the Parse model, and the only way I have found around it is to adjust your schema accordingly.

One way you could do it is with a relation on `A` that contains all related `User` pointers and then do a `$ne` against the relation field:

```
where: {
  'relationColumn' : {
    '$ne': {
      '__type': 'Pointer',
      'className': '_User',
      'objectId': 'user b id here'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah that looks really promising. Gonna look into it tomorrow.

Comment: On second look, it's not advised to store lots of data in an array relation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354495/parse-com-create-with-nested-or-related-objects/19343892#19343892).

Comment: A column of type `Array` is recommended for up to 100 items, a column of type `Relation` is for larger lists (it creates a full collection behind the scenes, so can handle millions of rows).